# kendoAutoComplete e.slice is not a function kendo.all.js

Tags: javascript, php, json, telerik

I have problem with Telerik UI for PHP.
i tried to post telerik AutoComplete but its not working here is code 
frontpage:

```
 function Adres_TTEditor(container, options) {
     $('<input data-text-field="Adres_TT" data-value-field="Adres_TT" data-bind="value:Adres_TT"  type="text"/>').appendTo(container).kendoAutoComplete({
                placeholder: "Enter place",
                dataTextField: 'Adres_TT',
                filter: "contains",
                dataSource: {
                    serverFiltering: true,
                    transport: {
                        read: {
                            url:  <?php echo $grid_path;?>+"grid.php?type=getAdres",
                            type: 'POST',
                            dataType: 'json'
                        }
                    }
                }
            })
     }
```

[Json result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sCSa3.png)

The following Error appears in the Console:

```
kendo.all.js:7112 Uncaught TypeError: e.slice is not a function
    at init.success (kendo.all.js:7112)
    at success (kendo.all.js:7035)
    at Object.i.success (kendo.all.js:6031)
    at i (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:2)
    at y (jquery.min.js:4)
    at XMLHttpRequest.c (jquery.min.js:4)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this error also.  I had to define a model in the schema.

```
.Schema(schema => schema
    .Data("Data")
    .Model(model =>
    {
        model.Id("id");
        model.Field("name", typeof(string));
    })
)
```

you can google this error and there are a lot of answers.